# Where clause not working in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Below is part of my sql code-

```
INTO #tmpRecDistData2
    FROM #TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs tr 
        FULL JOIN #tmpDistributorRecords td 
            ON  ( tr.RecUPC=td.DistUPC )
            where
            tr.RecSupplierInvoiceNumber=td.DistSupplierInvoiceNumber
```

Here where clause is not working and giving all result whether both invoices are same or different.
What may be the reason?

EDIT

```
RecSupplierInvoiceNumber       DistSupplierInvoiceNumber
00000000111807                                    6745
00000000111807                                    5635
00000000111807                                    5676
```

This is the output I am getting even after using where clause

```
SELECT td.DistSupplierInvoiceNumber,td.DistProductDescription,td.DistUPC,
       td.DistProductID, td.DistTranslationExists,td.DistInCatalog,      tr.RecSupplierInvoiceNumber,tr.RecProductDescription,tr.RecUPC,tr.RecProductID

    INTO #tmpRecDistData2
    FROM #TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs tr 
        FULL JOIN #tmpDistributorRecords td 
            ON  ( tr.RecUPC=td.DistUPC )
            WHERE RecSupplierInvoiceNumber=DistSupplierInvoiceNumber
```

Comment: doesn't seem like this could be true, actually. Are you absolutely completely sure this is happening?. There no other `OR <some other condition>` in your code?

Comment: It will act as `Inner Join` because of `Where` clause

Comment: Its true, even when I add condion 
where tr.RecSupplierInvoiceNumber='00111807',
it's not filtering data. Are these data coming from cached?

Comment: no, this shouldn't be happening (and I bet that it isn't happening really). There is no other conditions?, is this the whole code?

Comment: Do you mean, when you add where tr.RecSupplierInvoiceNumber='00111807', you're getting all of the distributor records, or that you're getting all of the rows from the TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs table?

Comment: @PraveenSingh Can you please provide sample data, the results you're getting, and your desired results?  I'm having some difficulty understanding what exactly the problem is.

Comment: yes, i am getting all records irrespective of mentioned invoice number

Comment: can you please answer if this is the whole code or not?

Comment: RecSupplierInvoiceNumber       DistSupplierInvoiceNumber

Comment: @PraveenSingh - We all are volunteers here nobody is paid for helping you when someone(Lamak) asks you something to help you, should be replying to it. Post your full query sample data of both the temp tables and expected result for your inputs

Comment: I have edited my question,please see that

Comment: and there's **absolutely no more code**?, how hard is it for you to answer this question?

Comment: @PraveenSingh Given the responses here, could you simulate the entire query in a site like http://sqlfiddle.com/? That would allow people to see your source data, the full query and the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try creating a self-contained example - the below code works fine for me.

Can you insert some sample data from your application into this toy code and see if it runs as you expect?  If it does, then the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs (
RecUPC VARCHAR(20),
RecSupplierInvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20),
Foobar VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpDistributorRecords  (
DistUPC VARCHAR(20),
DistSupplierInvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20),
Foobar VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs
(RecUPC,RecSupplierInvoiceNumber,Foobar)
VALUES
('ABC',22,'FooA'),
('ABD',23,'BarB'),
('BBB',30,'RecA'),
('BBB',31,'RecB')

INSERT INTO #tmpDistributorRecords
(DistUPC,DistSupplierInvoiceNumber,Foobar)
VALUES
('ABA',22,'FooC'),
('BBD',43,'BarD'),
('BBB',30,'DistA'),
('BBB',32,'DistB')


SELECT *
FROM #TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs tr 
        FULL JOIN #tmpDistributorRecords td 
            ON  ( tr.RecUPC=td.DistUPC )
            where
            tr.RecSupplierInvoiceNumber=td.DistSupplierInvoiceNumber

DROP TABLE #TempReceivingUnmatchedUPCs
DROP TABLE #tmpDistributorRecords
```

For me, this yields

```
RecUPC               RecSupplierInvoiceNumber Foobar               DistUPC              DistSupplierInvoiceNumber Foobar
-------------------- ------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------- --------------------
BBB                  30                       RecA                 BBB                  30                        DistA
```

And RecSupplierInvoiceNumber = DistSupplierInvoiceNumber as expected

Comment: This is same am trying to do and same output is expecting. Not even me, my senior developers are also confused why the where clause is not working.

Comment: @PraveenSingh I sincerely doubt you. I've asked several times in this question if this is the **whole** code or not, and you've refused to answer

Comment: @PraveenSingh That would suggest that somewhere else in the code, something else is inserting into #tmpRecDistData2 . . . can you search the rest of the code for other references to the table?

Comment: Sorry @Lamak, I am going to provide more possible code.